# Ansible Nested Loops from JSON

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need to map objects in JSON in the following way. Note that objects can have `bespokeVals` or not and the keys are dynamic.

```
[{
  "obj": "obj1",
    "bespokeVals": [
      {"key1": "val1"},
      {"key2": "val2"}
    ]
},
{
  "obj": "obj2",
    "bespokeVals": [
      {"key1": "val3"},
      {"key2": "val4"},
      {"key3": "val3"}
    ]
},
{
 "obj": "obj3",
   "bespokeVals": [
    {"randomKey": "vdsk"}
   ]
}]
```

What I want to do, is print `key=value` when `obj2 == something in Ansible`

This is as close as I've got so far. This is working but printing out `bespokeVals` as a:

```
- name: "Print Bespoke Vals"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.bespokeVals }}"
  loop: "{{ objectList }}"
  when: item.obj == something
```

If it helps, I have full control over the JSON so can change the format if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this probably what you're looking for? The play below

```
tasks:
  - name: "Print Bespoke Vals"
    debug:
       msg: "{{ item|dict2items|map(attribute='key')|join() }} =
             {{ item|dict2items|map(attribute='value')|join() }}"
    loop: "{{ objectList|json_query('[?obj == `obj2`].bespokeVals')|flatten }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "key1 = val3"
"msg": "key2 = val4"
"msg": "key3 = val3"
```